# httr API call for each row in a vector + mutate the response

Tags: r, httr, rcurl

I am trying to send a POST request to an API for each row in a vector, and I want to mutate the response given by the API as new columns (for each row aswell).

I get a 200 response with this query:

`this_works <- POST(url_predict, body= '{"text": "This is a bad thing"}')`

But now I want to substitute the text "This is a bad thing" for the text contained in each row of a dataframe.

My attempt so far:

```
bquery <- function(df){
  df3 <- data.frame()
  text_col <- toString(df4$text)
  url_predict = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict"
  this_doesnt_work <- POST(url_predict, body = paste("'{'", "text", "':'", text_col, "'}'", sep = ""))
  content1 <- content(this_doesnt_work)
  df3$bert_sentiment <- content1$sentiment
  df3$probability_negative <- content1$probabilities$negative
  df3$probability_neutral <- content1$probabilities$neutral
  df3$probability_positive <- content1$probabilities$positive
  df3$confidence <- content1$confidence
  df3
}
```

This doesn't work, however the output of my paste function appears as though it should work:

```
"'{'text':'This is a bad thing.'}'"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The response values from the server are:

```
$probabilities
$probabilities$negative
[1] 0.999736

$probabilities$neutral
[1] 0.0001732047

$probabilities$positive
[1] 9.086558e-05


$sentiment
[1] "negative"

$confidence
[1] 0.999736
```

I would like to mutate these values to the original dataset for each response/row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending one string value at a time :

```
bquery <- function(string){
   df3 <- data.frame()
   url_predict = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict"
   this_should_work <- POST(url_predict, body = sprintf('{"text":"%s"}',string))
   #Rest of the code
   #.....
   #.....
}
```

Then check if it works for one value :

```
bquery(df4$text[1])
```

If it does then use `lapply` for all :

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df4$text, bquery))
```

Or with `purrr::map_df`

```
purrr::map_df(df4$text, bquery)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I have tried and I am still getting a 400 bad request unfortunately :(

Comment: If this works `POST(url_predict, body= '{"text": "This is a bad thing"}')` and my answer doesn't the only difference I am seeing is of quotes. Can you try inverting the quotes? See updated answer.

Comment: You are correct the quotes are inverted on the correct query (sorry about that, many thanks for pointing this out) however the updated function is still returning a 400 bad request.

Comment: Interestingly the raw output of the sprintf call is the following: "\"{\"text\":\"This is a bad thing.\"}\""

Comment: Yes double quotes `""` are escaped while displaying. To see the "real"string use `cat`.

Comment: Very strange, I am getting 200 with POST(url_predict, body= '{"text": "This is a bad thing"}') but 400 with the sprintf implementation.

Comment: Does this work? `x <- "This is a bad thing"` and `POST(url_predict, body= sprintf('{"text": "%s"}', x))` ?

Comment: Ok...few extra quotes were present, i removed them from original answer. Try now. `bquery(df4$text[1])` Assuming you have `text` as character column and not factor.

Comment: This has worked thank you so much! If you could also help with a solution to mutating the response that would be amazing.

Comment: I have added the response values to the original question if that helps :)

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question please? It will help to keep this question only solving one problem.